# How to integrate Circulating results(Vectors) into dataframe.Grazie,guys

Tags: r

Happy newyear! Simulating a model pertaining to circulation, I encounter some questions here! I generate Y correctly as it makes no sense and adds NAs on dataframe into which I am planning to simulate Y 5000 times to integrate. I don't have a idea on that,and really appreciate for any help or suggestions, Guys! Thank[enter image description here][1]

[1]: [https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaFqA.png`#Investment](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kaFqA.png%60#Investment) simulation

```
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(statmod)
library(invGauss)
library(dplyr)
library(estimatr)
Res<-as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 27))
k=1
while(k <=5000){#this circulation probably collapesed
Y=c(1610,1550)
DeviaY=c(0)
Pos_value=c(0)
Years<-c(1986,1987)
DiffY=c(0)
prob_poi=(6/13)*(exp(1)^(-(6/13)))
expec<-c()
q <- rinvgauss(27, mean=0.5, disp=0.5) # generate vector of 10 random numbers
p <- pinvgauss(q, mean=0.5, disp=0.5) # p should be
uniformly distributed
for(i in 3:27){
  regree<-lm_robust(Y~Years)
  expec<- predict(regree,newdata=data.frame(Years=1985+i))
  DiffY[i-1]=0.7*(Y[i-1]-tail(expec,1))
  DeviaY[i-1]=p[i]*sd(Y)
  Pos_value[i-1]=sample(x=c(-1,1,0),replace = T,size = 1,prob = c(prob_poi/2,prob_poi/2,1-prob_poi))
  Y[i]<- Y[i-1]-DiffY[i-1]+DeviaY[i-1]+Pos_value[i-1]*rinvgauss(1,mean = 60,dispersion = 25)
  Years[i]<-1985+i
  if(i == 27) return(Y)
  }
Res[,k] <- Y#and corresponding to the first'while' on line 10
k<- k+1 #and corresponding to the first'while' on line 10
} #and corresponding to the first'while' on line 10

#My purpose is to repeat the correct calculating processes on line11 to line30 for framing dataframe,but it returns NAs and it make no sense.`
```

Comment: There is no error on single Y, while i can not integrate more simulations into dataframe when simulating more time, any suggestions from you kind guys

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question of loop when integrating consequential vectors into dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70595299/question-of-loop-when-integrating-consequential-vectors-into-dataframe)

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.