# Question on loop when integrating vectors into dataframe

Tags: r, loops, statistics, economics

Happy newyear! Simulating a model pertaining to circulation, I encounter some questions here! I generate Y correctly as it makes no sense and adds NAs on dataframe into which I am planning to simulate Y 5000 times to integrate. I don't have a idea on that,and really appreciate for any help or suggestions, Guys! Thanks!

```
 [#Investment simulation
library(tidyverse)
library(ggplot2)
library(statmod)
library(invGauss)
library(dplyr)
library(estimatr)
Res<-as.data.frame(matrix(nrow = 27))
k=1
while(k <=5000){#this circulation probably collapesed
Y=c(1610,1550)
DeviaY=c(0)
Pos_value=c(0)
Years<-c(1986,1987)
DiffY=c(0)
prob_poi=(6/13)*(exp(1)^(-(6/13)))
expec<-c()
q <- rinvgauss(27, mean=0.5, disp=0.5) # generate vector of 10 random numbers
p <- pinvgauss(q, mean=0.5, disp=0.5) # p should be uniformly distributed
for(i in 3:27){
  regree<-lm_robust(Y~Years)
  expec<- predict(regree,newdata=data.frame(Years=1985+i))
  DiffY\[i-1\]=0.7*(Y\[i-1\]-tail(expec,1))
  DeviaY\[i-1\]=p\[i\]*sd(Y)
  Pos_value\[i-1\]=sample(x=c(-1,1,0),replace = T,size = 1,prob = c(prob_poi/2,prob_poi/2,1-prob_poi))
  Y\[i\]<- Y\[i-1\]-DiffY\[i-1\]+DeviaY\[i-1\]+Pos_value\[i-1\]*rinvgauss(1,mean = 60,dispersion = 25)
  Years\[i\]<-1985+i
  if(i == 27) return(Y)
  }
Res\[,k\] <- Y#and corresponding to the first'while' on line 10
k<- k+1 #and corresponding to the first'while' on line 10
} #and corresponding to the first'while' on line 10

#My purpose is to repeat the correct calculating processes on line11 to line30 for framing dataframe,but it returns NAs and it make no sense.][1]
```

Comment: Please don't post essentially the same question multiple times: [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70590463/how-to-integrate-circulating-resultsvectors-into-dataframe-grazie-guys) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70595299/question-of-loop-when-integrating-consequential-vectors-into-dataframe).    Either update the orignal question or delete it if you feel that is more appropriate.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Question of loop when integrating consequential vectors into dataframe](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70595299/question-of-loop-when-integrating-consequential-vectors-into-dataframe)

Comment: @Oliver: the link you give is to the same question posted by the same OP earlier today.

Comment: It appears you are using code from an article, which probably for some sort of markdown/markup purposes uses `'\'` as escapes, for the purposes of publication formatting, that are not used in R code. Perhaps if you remove all '`'\'`, you'll start seeing better results.

Comment: @Limey sadly that is the message that gets posted when you try to close it due to being a duplicate. ^^

Comment: Really appreciate, I add a break into the first loop and it makes sense. Grazie! @Oliver@Limey@Chris Happy newyear guys

Comment: @Oliver.  Fair point.  My bad.  Apologies.